# Next 14: how to set cookie in middleware and get it in root layout

Tags: next.js, cookies, middleware, next.js14

react: 18.2.0
next": 14.0.3

my goal is to guarantee existence of a cookie with session id from very beginning. i use middleware for that.

```
export async function middleware(req: nextrequest) {
   const response = nextresponse.next();
    const ensuredsessionid = await fetchensuresession(
      req.nexturl.origin,
      currentsessionid,
    );
    console.log(`ensured sessionid for url ${req.url}`, ensuredsessionid);
    response.cookies.set("sessionid", ensuredsessionid, {
      path: "/",
      httponly: true,
      samesite: "strict",
      secure: true,
    });

    return response;
    }
```

I want to use the cookie in my root layout.tsx but it's undefined. However, I can see it in browser's dev tools despite it was undefined in layout. and if I refresh the page, next time i get the cookie in my layout.tsx instantly.

```
import { cartprovider } from "@storefront/shell/cart/cartcontext";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

interface props {
 children: react.reactnode;
}

export default async function rootlayout({ children }: props) {
 const session = cookies().get("sessionid");

 console.log("session-Id", session);

 return (
   <cartprovider sessionid={session?.value}>{children}</cartprovider>
 );
}
```

i expect  cookie to be there initially since middleware comes before the layout.tsx. but it's not there. Next.js logs:

```
✓ Ready in 1773ms
✓ Compiled /src/middleware in 178ms (163 modules)
✓ Compiled /api/ensure-session in 455ms (33 modules)
ensured sessionId for url https://localhost:3000/en f142d570-93a7-4503-a52e-7f9fe580b89f
 ○ Compiling /[lang] ...
 ✓ Compiled /[lang] in 2.9s (3517 modules)
Session-Id undefined
 ○ Compiling /api/trpc/[trpc] ...
 ✓ Compiled /api/trpc/[trpc] in 573ms (2083 modules)
```

could anyone tell me what i'm missing about understanding of how next.js cookies works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i've got it!
When you set cookie in middleware the layout.tsx do not has already set cookie header in it's request indeed, but instead middleware pass a header to set it. Absolutely logical. Hence, to catch it up initially in first render of any RSC like layout.tsx you must look not into cookies() since it hadn't been set yet, but in headers() set-cookies since it gonna be set on response.

Answer (score 0):

when the middleware sets a cookie and then immediately after, during the same request-response cycle, an rsc tries to read that cookie, it's undefined yet because cookie was just set on the response being sent back.

this means the client's browser has not yet received the response with the new cookies, therefore, the cookie value isn't available to be sent back to the server in the headers of the request that is rendering the rsc.

when I navigate away or refresh the page, the browser sends a new request to the server. this time, the request includes all cookies relevant to the domain

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is missing a little information, but I understand that the error is probably being generated by the life cycle of the cookies. The middleware runs on the server and the cookie object is only available on the server and is not automatically sent to the client, so when you try to access from the client (layout or page) to `cookies().get('sessionid' )`  returns `undefined`. For this reason, when updating the website it returns the value of `sessionid` without problems.

It occurs to me that you can try to get the `sessionid` value with the `getServerSideProps()` function, but I'm honestly not 100% sure it will work in your case because I don't have enough information.

I suggest you read the following Next js documentation, which explains this in more depth.

- https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies
- https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/authentication#session-management